# Crear un array de tamaño pasado por teclado con números primos aleatorios

Tags: java, algoritmos, netbeans-8.2

Buen dia, me encuentro tomando una clase de algoritmos y me dejan el siguiente ejercicio:

> Crear un array de números de un tamaño pasado por teclado, el array contendrá números aleatorios primos.

He buscado información en internet para guiarme pero no he tenido éxito, les agradezco que por favor me ayuden, este es el código que he hecho hasta el momento:

```java
public class EJ1_N2_ARREGLOS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //CREAR UNA ARRAY DE NÚMEROS DE UN TAMAÑO PASADO POR TECLADO, EL ARRAY CONTENDRÁ NÚMEROS ALEATORIOS PRIMOS.
        int TAMAÑO = 0;
        TAMAÑO = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE EL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO (NÚMERO): "));
        
        int [] N_PRIMOS = new int [TAMAÑO];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < N_PRIMOS.length; i++) {
            N_PRIMOS[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100);
            System.out.print(N_PRIMOS[i]+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual seria el problema?

Comment: StackOverflow es para realizar preguntas concretas de los [temas permitidos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Lo que has publicado actualmente no me deja clara cual es esa duda concreta que tienes y en su forma actual me temo que terminará siendo cerrada por la comunidad. Por favor editala para añadir más detalle.

Comment: Generar números al azar para después verificar si son o no son primos es bastante ineficiente, pues es más probable que el número no sea primo. Ya que el enunciado no aclara que tengan que ser diferentes, ni cómo se deben generar esos primos, yo crearía de antemano un array que contenga solo primos (no aleatorios) usando algoritmos típicos para generar primos (ej: criba de eratóstenes). Después rellenaría el array que te piden eligiendo al azar índices del primer array y sacando de ahí los valores seleccionados por el índice.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class ArrayDePrimos {

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    //Pedimos por consola el tamaño deseado del array
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce el tamaño deseado para tu array porfavor: ");
    int tamaño = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

    int array_primos[] = new int[tamaño]; // Creamos el array con el tamaño

    int cantidadPrimos = 0, numero = 0;

    while(cantidadPrimos < array_primos.length){

        numero = (int) (Math.random()*1000 + 1);

        if(esPrimo(numero) == true){

            array_primos[cantidadPrimos] = numero;
            System.out.println(array_primos[cantidadPrimos]);
            cantidadPrimos++; //Aumentamos el contador para poder rellenar la siguiente posición del array
        }

    }
    
}

public static boolean esPrimo(int num){ //Función que determina si es primo

        int contador = 2;
        boolean primo = true;

        while(contador < num){

            if(num % contador == 0){
    
                primo = false;
                break;

            }else{

                contador++;
            }
        }
            
        return primo;

}
```

}

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Dada la información que has dado esta es una solución válida. Un saludo :)